# How to expand all portions of an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider a toy expression:

```
expr = Sin[x (a + b)]/(y (z + c))
```

I would like to expand all parentheses to get something like:

```
Sin[a x + b x]/(c y + y z)
```

I have been able to expand the argument of the `Sin` term using:

```
MapAll[Expand,expr]
(* Out[] = Sin[a x + b x]/(y (c + z)) *)
```

However, this leaves the denominator unexpanded. Is there a way to expand the entire expression?

Comment: ExpandAll will do this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, I found that function like 2 seconds after I posted the question. Any idea why regular `Expand` won't do it?

Comment: Best I recall it was only meant to handle polynomial-like things. Before my time, really.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau _"Before my time"_ whaa? Aren't you a dinosaur at WRI?

Comment: No, just a mastodon. Mastodanny, actually, but they are cousin species.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the `ExpandDenominator` function which, as the name implies, expands the denominator of the expression. Then, `Expand` and `ExpandDenominator` can be cobbled together using:

```
ExpandDenominator //@ Expand //@ expr
```

(Thanks Mr. Wizard for the improved cleanliness.) However, there is also a related built-in function that does this all in one shot:

```
ExpandAll[expr]
(* Out[] = Sin[a x + b x]/(c y + y z) *)
```

Comment: The first line looks better (to my eye) as: `ExpandDenominator //@ Expand //@ expr`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good call. Edited the post to clean up that expression.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that an expression like `1/((a + b) x)` is totally deceiving.
It doesn't remain unevaluated, it evaluates to something, but that other something is formatted in the same way as the original.

```
1/((a + b) x) // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> Times[1, Power[Times[Plus[a, b], x], -1]]

```
1/((a + b) x) // FullForm
```

> Times[Power[Plus[a, b], -1], Power[x, -1]]

So, as you can see, it evaluates to something that should look like `1/(a+b) 1/x`
That's why `Expand` never gets mapped to a polynomial denominator.

Try, for example

```
Expand//@Unevaluated[Sin[x (a + b)]/(y (z + c))]
```

> Sin[a x + b x]/(c y + y z)